# How can I show "run" console in pyqt GUI (QTdesigner)?

Tags: user-interface, printing, pyqt4, qt-designer

I'm making a web crawling GUI using selenium and PyQt (Qt designer)
before I used GUI, 
I checked my process in web crawling using print
like :

```
for i / len(href_list):
 print (i,"/", len(href),"processing..")
```

then,
I get

```
1/10 processing...
2/10 processing...
```

in pycharm 'run' console.

But In GUI, there are no 'run' console (even their is prompt window behind my GUI)So I cannot check my progress.
I think I can solve this problem using 'Text browser' in Qt designer,
but I don't know how to connect this module.

**so, My question is how can I show (print('blablabla')) in GUI?**

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options in PyQT.

For example, by using QPlainTextEdit you may create console-like box within your GUI.

see:
[PyQt Multiline Text Input Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239114/pyqt-multiline-text-input-box)

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qplaintextedit.html